# MS Access SQL Subquery (count) changes value of IFF logic outcome

Tags: sql, subquery, ms-access-2016

MS Access 2016

I have the following query that works as excepted.  The IIF first condition IsNull(caseDecision.completeFlag) resolves true when the completedFlag is null.

```
SELECT 
  client.*
  , IIf(IsNull(caseDecision.completeFlag),
    "",
    IIf(caseDecision.completeFlag=True,"YES","STARTED")) AS completeFlag
  , caseDecision.decisionNum
FROM client LEFT JOIN caseDecision ON client.kcas_key = caseDecision.kcas_key
WHERE caseDecision.decisionNum = 1
  OR caseDecision.decisionNum IS NULL
ORDER BY client.kcas_key DESC;
```

When I add the following sub query:

```
  , (SELECT COUNT(kcas_key) FROM caseDecision as cd WHERE cd.kcas_key = client.kcas_key) AS cnt
```

The mentioned IIF(IsNull(caseDecision.completeFlag), is never true.  So that subquery seems to be impacting the IIF.  Any ideas?

Here is the SQL with the subquery

```
SELECT 
  client.*
  , IIf(IsNull(caseDecision.completeFlag),
    "",
    IIf(caseDecision.completeFlag=True,"YES","STARTED")) AS completeFlag
  , caseDecision.decisionNum
  , (SELECT COUNT(kcas_key) FROM caseDecision as cd WHERE cd.kcas_key = client.kcas_key) AS cnt
FROM client LEFT JOIN caseDecision ON client.kcas_key = caseDecision.kcas_key
WHERE caseDecision.decisionNum = 1
  OR caseDecision.decisionNum IS NULL
ORDER BY client.kcas_key DESC;
```

Comment: I can't see how a subquery changes evaluation of a separate `IIF` expression. Please show data for [mcve].

Comment: @Parfait: Agreed I should have provided a reproducible example but I'm dealing with sensitive data.  When I get a moment I'll see if I can provide a sterilized reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `nz` function as follows:

```
IIf(nz(caseDecision.completeFlag, Flase)=True, "YES", "STARTED"))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  While it did not solve my issue, it allowed me to figure out the a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution.
First, a little row count data.

- Table: client = 64K records.
- Table: caseDecision = 360.

And

- Column caseDecision.completeFlag is a Boolean  (Yes/No)

The SQL contains a LEFT JOIN with one other table.  Here is the initial SQL:

```
SELECT 
  client.*
  , IIf(IsNull(caseDecision.completeFlag),
    "",
    IIf(caseDecision.completeFlag=True,"YES","STARTED")) AS completeFlag
  , caseDecision.decisionNum
FROM client 
LEFT JOIN caseDecision ON client.kcas_key = caseDecision.kcas_key
WHERE caseDecision.decisionNum = 1
  OR caseDecision.decisionNum IS NULL
ORDER BY client.kcas_key DESC;
```

So for the majority or return records caseDecision.completeFlag will be NULL

However when I add in the subquery:

```
(SELECT COUNT(kcas_key) FROM caseDecision as cd WHERE cd.kcas_key = client.kcas_key) AS cnt
```

caseDecision.completedFlag seems to get set to its default value of False.  I would have thought it would be NULL given the LEFT JOIN.

So what I did is replace the caseDecision.completeFlag with a different column from table caseDecision. I used a numeric value instead of Yes/No (Boolean).  In a LEFT JOIN it returns a NULL unless there is a match.  Now my SQL works as I hoped it would.

```
SELECT client.* 
  ,IIF(IsNull(caseDecision.decisionNum),
      "",
      IIF(caseDecision.completeFlag=True,"YES","STARTED")) AS completeFlag
  ,caseDecision.decisionNum
  ,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM caseDecision WHERE caseDecision.kcas_key = client.kcas_key) AS cnt
FROM client 
LEFT JOIN caseDecision ON client.kcas_key = caseDecision.kcas_key
WHERE caseDecision.decisionNum = 1
  OR caseDecision.decisionNum IS NULL
ORDER BY client.kcas_key DESC;
```